# Why does this applet view an empty applet window

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

```
package assignment3;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

public class test extends Applet {

    private Image logo1;

    public void init() {
        logo1 = getImage( getCodeBase(), "bg.jpg" );
    }

    @Override
    public void paint( Graphics g ) {
        g.drawImage( logo1, 0, 0, this );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post more details. It is very unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

put .jpg,.html,.class file in same folder then run .html file with applet viewer or with browser.